# If the Earth were perfectly isolated (no energy or matter going in or out), would all processes be recyclable and reversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

If the Earth were perfectly isolated from the rest of the universe - with no exchange of matter, energy, radiation etc - would we be able to recycle all stuff on Earth perfectly? For example, simple processes like electrolysis and burning of hydrogen. If no energy or matter is lost during these events, what's preventing us from reversing and recycling them indefinitely?

Comment: The Earth is almost perfectly isolated. We are losing a trivial amount of hydrogen to space and a non-trivial amount of helium (which is our own fault). The only other matter that gets lost irreversibly consists of radioactive nuclides and we could, in theory, replace those.

Answer (score 5):

> If the Earth were perfectly isolated ... would all processes be recyclable and reversible ?

Good question. The answer is no. The [first law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics) tells us that energy must be conserved. However, the [second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) tells us that even in a closed system in which the total energy does not change, physical processes are still in general irreversible, because they tend to increase [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy). The system as a whole moves towards a state of [thermodynamic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium) in which entropy is maximised, no more useful work can be extracted, and no further macroscopic change can take place.

Comment: Penrose has a lecture where he explains that the entropy of inbound solar photons is much less than the entropy of thermal radiation back to space. So while every knows the Sun provides life with energy, Penrose points out that the temperature difference between the Sun and space (5772K vs 2.7K) also us to radiate entropy, leaving order behind.